# Embedding Chakra javascript engine failed to initialize COM interfaces

Tags: javascript, c#, c++, dll, com

I just compiled ChakraCore and run Hello World Sample.

when I built ChakraCore there was no error found.

But when I run HelloWorld sampl System.Runtime.InetropServices.SEHException occured at *ChakraHost.Hosting.Native.JsCreateContext(JavaScriptRuntime runtime, JavaScriptContext& newContext)*.

It said external component has thrown an exception.

So I enabled native code debugging and found assertion failure in ChakraCore and Assert message is like below.

*AssertMsg(false, "Failed to initialize COM interfaces, verify correct version of globalization dll is used.");*

Then I searched for system.globalization.dll file and found the file in multiple folders.

I copied it into C:\windows\SysWOW64 and ran regsvr32 system.globalization.dll.

I got below message from the run.

*The module "system.globalization.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. 
Make sure that "system.globalization.dll"is a valid DLL or OCS file and theny try again.*

I don't know what to do now. I have spend hours to solve this problem.

Can anyone help me figure this out please?

Thanks,

Comment: spending hours digging into dll files to get a simple helloworld working is the exact  reason i got into JS...

Comment: The globalization DLL file name is "Windows.Globalization.dll", not "system.globalization.dll"

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get it working.

1. Build ChakraCore from Visual Studio 2015. I used debug and x64
2. Copy ChakraCore/Build/VcBuild/bin/x64_debug.ChakraCore.dll to Chakra-Samples\ChakraCore Samples\Hello World\C#\HelloWorld\bin
3. Go to HelloWorld solution properties and set Platform target to x64
4. Add breakpoint in Main method of HelloWorld press F5.

In my case the failing line was always:

```
// Create a runtime. 
Native.JsCreateRuntime(JavaScriptRuntimeAttributes.None, null, out runtime);
```

After taking the actions mentioned above I get the HelloWorld sample to run.

Hope this helps.